# What is the expiry time of a environment variables?

Tags: node.js, jwt, environment-variables

I am setting a environment variable in jwt for authentication in my node project but I am little bit confused about the expiry time of the environment variable.

Comment: where did you read about *the expiry time of the environment variable*?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to ask? can you be more specific?

Comment: you asked about *the expiry time of the environment variable* Where did you hear or read about this? I never heard the term *the expiry time of the environment variable*, but if you ask about it, just must have it from somewhere.

Comment: Ok, now i get it. Actually i was working with environment variable in my latest node project where i had to set a environment variable which i used to generate a jwt token during login. so it occurred to me that, have I need to set that environment variable every time I run my node project. so I try to googling it but couldn't find any solution until now. Actually I am new to environment variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The environmental variables themselves do not expire. Once they are set, they will never disappear (unless you explicitly unset them).

In the context of JSON Web Tokens (JWT) you can set a maximum token validity duration (expiration time).

From [JWT RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519):

> The "exp" (expiration time) claim identifies the expiration time on or
> after which the JWT MUST NOT be accepted for processing. The
> processing of the "exp" claim requires that the current date/time MUST
> be before the expiration date/time listed in the "exp" claim.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, It helps to clear my doubt. :)